# Deploy website using Git/Gitolite [post-receive hook doesn't work properly]

Tags: git, deployment, web-deployment, gitolite, git-post-receive

I'm trying to deploy my website using git/gitolite.

I've created a remote repository, I cloned it to my local machine.

I've 2 branches Master and develop.

I've created a script of post-receive hook in order to deploy each branch in the correct web directory :

`/var/www/<mysite>/` for branch Master [live version]
`/var/www/<mysite>/dev` for branch develop [dev version]

for that I'm using this script in `.gitolite/hooks/common/post-receive` file :

```
#!/bin/bash
prodroot="/var/www/<mysite>"
devroot="/var/www/<mysite>/dev"

while read oldrev newrev ref
do
branch=`echo $ref | cut -d/ -f3`
if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
        sudo git --work-tree=$prodroot  checkout -f
        sudo chown -R webuser:psacln $prodroot
else
        echo "Push on dev branch"
        sudo git --work-tree=$devroot  checkout -f 
        sudo chown -R webuser:psacln $devroot
fi
done
```

If I use it this way, it doesn't work properly, because `checkout -f`  always get master branch, in other side if I use `checkout -f $branch` I'm getting an error saying :

```
fatal: '/home/git/repositories/<mysite>.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

And every thing fall down, I'm obliged to create repositories [Using gitolite].

What I want to understand is :  if it's not a git directory, why it works for `checkout -f` [MASTER] and not for `checkout -f $branch` [here DEVELOP] ?

Am I missing something ? Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In this type of hook, try t:

- add `unset GIT_DIR` at the beginning of the script
- always use the `--git-dir=/path/to/your/repo.git` in addition of the --`work-tree=` option.

That way, any `git` command will know exactly where (`--work-tree`) and for which git repo (`--git-dir`) it is supposed to be executed.

Comment: Thank you VonC, I tried it this way but it doesn't work, Am I supposed to put my remote repository in --git-dir=/path/to/your/repo.git ?

Comment: @AdilOuchraa no: the path to your local cloned git repo.

Comment: How to ? I'm currently in remote, and also post-receive file is in the remote ?

Comment: @AdilOuchraa that is, the path of the local cloned repo which your hook can see on its side.

Comment: I dont get your point @VonC, can you give more details please

Comment: @AdilOuchraa your post-receive hook must unset GIT_DIR, and specify `--git-dir=/path/to/gitolite/yourRepo.git` (plus `work-tree=` the right path) the path of the gitolite-managed repo that your hook can see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Coloq

```
if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    cd $prodroot  
    sudo git pull //first time do git clone
    sudo chown -R webuser:psacln $prodroot  // what group is psacln ?
```

Comment: it's been a long time ago Colok :D Now I'm using Ansible to perform deploy operations.

Thanks.