# Git does not recognize repositories while executing a hook

Tags: git, bash, ssh

In my post-receive hooks I want to run this simple hook which is actually just two lines if you take out the echos and what not.

I verified the commands are correct by ssh(ing) into the server and double checking the paths.

However I get this error:

> remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

What does the '.' mean and why does it not work.  If I type these command in manually while on the server they work fine.

But in the hook they do not.

**post-receive hook**

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "****"
echo "*****"
echo "start:post-receive"
echo "*****"
echo "****"

cd /home/user_name/public_html
git pull /home/user_name/root.git master

echo "****"
echo "*****"
echo "end:post-receive"
echo "*****"
echo "****"
```

Comment: If you're going to try running `git` commands in your `post-receive` hook you will probably need to unset the `GIT_DIR` environment variable.  Try that and see what happens.

Comment: Can you tell me what this used for ?  I ran `set` from the shell and did not see it listed.

Answer (score 0):

> I ran set from the shell and did not see it listed

That because it is set during the execution of the hook itself.
See what an `echo $GIT_DIR` tells you in that hook script.

By doing "`unset GIT_DIR`", you will force git to look for the git directory where you just changed folder: in `/home/user_name/public_html` (which should have a `.git` subfolder)

I also suggests to use the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` options in any git command in a hook. That way, there is no surprise. See for example "[Deploy website using Git/Gitolite (`post-receive` hook doesn't work properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20702499/6309)"